# Custom UILabel class does not change properties?

Tags: swift, xcode, class, uilabel

I have a custom `UILabel` class. I create one `CustomLabel` and positioned it but it doesn't have properties that I gave in the custom `UILabel` class.

```
class CustomLabel: UILabel {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        textAlignment = .center
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

and here is my ViewController

```
class Controller: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let lblPos = CGRect(x: view.frame.size.width / 2 - 75 , y: 100, width: 150 , height: 30)
        let samsungLbl = CustomLabel(frame: lblPos)
        samsungLbl.text = "Samsung"
        view.addSubview(samsungLbl)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you set properties at `awakeFromNib` method. From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1402907-awakefromnib)

> **awakeFromNib()**
>
> The nib-loading infrastructure sends an awakeFromNib message to each object recreated from a nib archive

So this method is called when your object is loaded from a `.xib` file or a storyboad. Since you creating your object programmatically by calling `init(frame: CGRect)`, your `awaktFromNib` is never called.

You need to move your setup code into another method and call from the initializer.

```
func setupStyle() {
    backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    textAlignment = .center
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.setupStyle()
}
```

Comment: ah this makes sense. Thank you